# Different name on passport and in employment letter for 189 visa

Tags: australia

Someone, please help me with this.

I have all my documents till my graduation ( all marksheets, degree certificate, pan card and even passport ) with only my first name , say ABCD. I am done with my PTE test and now want to get my skills assessment to be done by ACS. I have my full name mentioned with my employer, say ABCD XYZ, so I will get the employment letter with full name only.

Now I am not sure how to go ahead with ACS assessment.
1) do I need to provide  any one of these - gadget/ notarized letter/ affidavit etc  along with my employment letter and marksheets to ACS, is there a provision to add such certificate while submitting other documents

2) is there any other way, this could be handled.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: My citizenship is Indian